# Pegar apenas uma parte de uma url

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde!
Como posso pegar apenas uma parte de uma url atual?
Por exemplo, digamos que tenho a seguinte url:

http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/player.html?ip=dispensacao#15

Gostaria de obter apenas o valor que vem depois de `?ip=` neste caso `dispensacao#15`

Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize a função [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) do Javascript, assim:

OBS: o exemplo irá printar um alert undefined pois nao existe uma url com o parâmetro "?ip=", mas teste com a sua url que irá funcionar.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
            <script>                                        
              var url = window.location.href;
              url = url.split('?ip=');
              url = url[1];
              alert(url);
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works like a charm!
Muito obrigado

Comment: Show de boleta.

Answer (score 1):

ES2015 (ES6)

```
const getParams = query => {
  if (!query) {
    return { };
  }

  return (/^[?#]/.test(query) ? query.slice(1) : query)
    .split('&')
    .reduce((params, param) => {
      let [ key, value ] = param.split('=');
      params[key] = value ? decodeURIComponent(value.replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : '';
      return params;
    }, { });
};
```

Sem jQuery

```
var qs = (function(a) {
    if (a == "") return {};
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {
        var p=a[i].split('=', 2);
        if (p.length == 1)
            b[p[0]] = "";
        else
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));
```

Com a URL `?topic=123&name=query+string`, o retorno seria:

```
qs["topic"];    // 123
qs["name"];     // query string
qs["nothere"];  // undefined (object)
```

Answer (score 1):

O javascript possui por padrão esta informação em `window.location` e para obter o valor mais facilmente pode-se usar a classe de URL.

```
var url = new URL(window.location);
var ip = url.searchParams.get("ip");
```

O valor estará na variável `ip`.

Comment: Muito pratico, funciona em todos os navegadores atuais?

Comment: Pelo que eu vi na documentação da Mozilla o Internet Explorer não roda https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URL/URL 
o Microsoft Edge se não roda ainda, ele irá rodar, pq existe uma issue no site deles que diz que será implementado nos próximos updates.https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8993198/

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams

Essa tabela coloca o Edge a partir da versão 17

Comment: Perdão, no meu exemplo eu uso a classe URL e nao a URLSearchParams. Portanto o Edge já suporta sim
https://caniuse.com/#feat=url

Comment: Ah maravilha, eu ainda não explorei todas as possibilidades em variados navegadores, principalmente o EDGE, mas mesmo assim obrigado por esclarecer.

Answer (score 1):

A função javascript abaixo retorna um array/objeto com os parâmetros e valores das variáveis da url corrente.

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Ex:`http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/player.html?ip=dispensacao#15&site=leituracrista`

chamando a função getUrlVars(), considerando a url acima, teremos o seguinte retorno:

```
{
    "ip"    : "dispensacao#15",
    "site" : "leituracrista"
}
```

**para pegar o valor do primeiro parâmetro seria assim:**

```
var first = getUrlVars()["ip"];      //dispensacao#15
```

**o segundo:**

```
var second = getUrlVars()["site"];   //leituracrista
```

[**Fonte**](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com.br/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim, e verja se serve:

```
window.location.search
```

Comment: isso me retorna "?ip=dispensacao" mas não queria o ?ip= e queria pergar o fnal do url tbm

Comment: Então, mas aí tem um problema.
Quando você coloca aquele # no fim, o navegador entende como âncora. Por isso ele não vem no valor. Recomendo que retire o # e coloque um _ ou algo assim. Daí, da um split ou algo assim.

Comment: Dica, ponha no console do chrome "window.location" e veja as opções que lhe aparecem. Se alguma lhe vale a pena.

Comment: Vou testar, obrigado

Comment: no seu caso específico a solução será `window.location.search.substr(3) + window.location.hash`

Comment: mas não considero uma boa prática fazer desta forma que coloquei, e concordo com o que o Diego disse sobre usar hash na url.

Comment: neste caso seria `substr(4)` para retirar o `=` também, vlw @KarlZillner